# How to add links to the top menu of Magento site when there is already a left menu?

Tags: magento

Can anyone tell me how to add links to the top menu of my Magento site.

Here it is - http://www.westoztools.com.au/working/index.php/

Please note that I have a left menu as well.

Answer (score 0):

The way the top menu is built depends highly on your theme.
But if the theme follows standard behavior then you could add a link in the top menu through any layout xml file like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
             <label>LINK LABEL HERE</label>
             <url>relative url here</url>
             <title>Link title here</title>
             <prepare>1</prepare>
             <urlParams/>
             <position>100</position> <!-- feel free to change this -->
         </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```